# Jquery datatable traverse rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, datatable

I have specific requirement for datatable using query. I am looking for solution.

I have datatable with rows , each row is either parent row of any other row or child row of other parent row.

I want to Implement button as one of the column, when it is clicked  it should scroll me to the parent row.  Each row has its own guid and holds value of its parent row's guid.

Open for all kind of solution. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are many rows in your question :) Can you show any code?

Comment: That is what I am looking for. As of now I am using datatable in common way like jquery provides. My requirement is mentioned above which is  to traverse  to parent row through guid identity. Each row has unique guid and have also value of parent row guid. I am looking for efficient way of implementing this requirement.

Comment: Got the answer. In click event I need to return false. Or I need to use prevantDefault() on event argument object.